# What is the difference between sorting an array of times in MacOs vs Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, macos, performance, ubuntu, time

I was working on a performance improvement for a query, which returns a list of objects sorted by date. My first implementation was as follows:

`times.sort { |t1, t2| t1 <=> t2 }`

For a large array, this was taking more time that I'd like. A rewrite to

`times.sort { |t1, t2| t1.to_i <=> t2.to_i }`

greatly improved performance (by a factor 4-5). This puzzled me a bit, but it improved performance, so even though I couldn't find out why, I submitted it for code review.

One of my colleagues reviewed my code, and was surprised about my claim, as he couldn't reproduce it. We ran some benchmarking with the following code:

```
now = Time.now
last_year = now - 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
times = []
10000.times { times.push rand(last_year..now) }

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { times.sort { |t1, t2| t1 <=> t2 } }
  x.report { times.sort { |t1, t2| t1.to_i <=> t2.to_i } }
end
```

and were very confused to find (reproduced over >5 runs):

on OSX (10.10.2):

```
   user     system      total        real
1.860000   2.570000   4.430000 (  4.604914)
1.250000   0.030000   1.280000 (  1.418240)
```

on Ubuntu (3.13.0-37-generic, 64 bits)

```
   user     system      total        real
0.920000   0.060000   0.980000 (  0.985049)
0.990000   0.000000   0.990000 (  0.993462)
```

The absolute time difference doesn't bother me so much, as my colleague's machine might simply be less heavily loaded, but the entire performance gain has disappeared!

What could possibly cause this difference?

Comment: Did you make sure you used the absolutely same ruby versions? If yes, this might be still caused by different ruby interpretors.

Comment: It does look like there are some differences in https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/time.c depending on the size of various types available (e.g. is there a 64 bit int type etc)

Comment: On my system (Ruby 2.2/OS X) `t1.to_i <=> t2.to_i` is *slower* by a factor of 10, but you probably should use `sort_by(&:to_i)` either way :-)

Comment: @mudasobwa Both pc's are running ruby 2.1.5p273